# Angularjs not working with rails_api in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Rails API` and i put my `angularjs` `index.html` file (alongwith all directory structure) into `public` folder of my `api` . It works great in `development enviroment` but when i try to start it `production` it gives `404` in browser . I don't why ! . 
will i have to `precompile` the code ? but i don't think so because

- my files are in `public folder` not the `app/assets/javascript`
- more is that i have my own folders names in which i placed the
  libraries of `angular` , `css` and etc .

  **Note:** I'm using `rails api` where no `javascript` folder exists in `app/assets`

Any help will be appreciating

Comment: You get 404 - when fetching what?

Comment: when i hit the server but shows the app running when i start it in development mode

Comment: You hit your server mutliple time when loading the website - first time when fetching html and then every time browser requests css, js or an image. So which request gives you 404? Might be easier if you give us the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `config.serve_static_files = true` in `production.rb` and will work fine :)